# How to copy all editing steps (not just settings) In Lightroom?

Tags: software, post-processing, lightroom

Is there a way to copy the editing steps from one image and paste them to another image in Lightroom, rather than simply copy/pasting the settings?

I use a number of presets in Lightroom. When copying an image's settings and pasting it to a new image, I lose the edit history. I'd prefer to duplicate the whole edit history, so I can easily identify which presets I've applied to each image.

Is there any way to do this in Lightroom, whether via a plugin or via the standard interface? I'm working with Lightroom 4.4 at the moment.

Comment: What if you `Export as Catalog`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such a feature now, but you can vote for it on [Adobe site](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/copy_steps_not_sync_settings_copy_change_stack), where a user proposed this feature over two years ago.